# How can I query the transaction number of a liquidity pool in PancakeSwap?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, bsc, bscscan, subgraph

I want to query the transaction numbers of the liquidity pools of PancakeSwap and so that decide which 10000 of them are the most active ones (there are 1.2M). How can I do this using Ethers.js or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the 1k pairs with this function:

```
const getAllPairs = async () => {
    try {
        let pairs = []
        for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            const result = await factory.allPairs(i)
            pairs.push(result)
        }
        console.log(pairs)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

And order by `totalSupply()`